# One liner - Nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Trying to avoid nested for loops but I'm unsure how I shall use `words = x.split()` and `words[y:y+n]` inside the one liner.

```
n = 1
for x in data:
    words = x.split()
    for y in range(len(words)-n+1):
        print(words[y:y+n])
```

So far I'm working with the following:

```
data = ' '.join([(x, y) for x in data words = x.split() for y in range(len(words)-n+1) words[y:y+n]])
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? the explicit loop is much easier to understand

Comment: @Sayse Need the output data in one list so I can use it further with N-grams.

Comment: So just append it to a list rather than printing to a console?

Comment: @Sayse Could work but want to know how to do it as one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to assigning a temporary variable is to iterate over a 1-tuple instead:

```
data = ' '.join(words[y:y+n] for x in data for words in (x.split(),) for y in range(len(words)-n+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 1
for x in data:
    words = x.split()
    for y in range(len(words)-n+1):
        print(words[y:y+n])
```

n is never changed so always 1

```
for x in data:
    words = x.split()
    for y in range(len(words)-1+1):
        print(words[y:y+1])
```

so simplify that

```
for x in data:
    words = x.split()
    for y in range(len(words)):
        print(words[y])
```

which is basically

```
for x in data:
    for word in x.split():
        print(word)
```

which get us to

```
data=' '.join(word for x in data for word in x.split())
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately is n a part of a function and can therefor change to get different N-grams